# Can be the following query further optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, query-optimization

I have the following SQL query and personally i can't find a way to optimize this further.
Do you agree with me?

This is the query:

```
select
   t1.queue,
   t.accountcode as agent,
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, time1, t.calldate) as recall_time 
from
   daily_cdr t 
   inner join
      (
         select
            a.callid,
            a.data2 as caller,
            Cast(a.time as datetime) as time1,
            a.queuename as queue 
         from
            queue_log a 
            inner join
               queue_log b 
               on a.callid = b.callid 
         where
            a.event = "ENTERQUEUE" 
      )
      t1 
      on t.dst = t1.caller 
where
   disposition = "ANSWERED" 
   and billsec > 0 
   and t.calldate > t1.time1 
   and t.accountcode is not null 
group by
   uniqueid;
```

It will be executed on a **5.5.68-MariaDB** instance.

I started from a query made by several subqueries.

The next is only a part of the initial query to give you an idea of how it was:

```
    select
    (
       select
          data2 
       from
          queue_log 
       where
          callid = t.callid 
          and event = "ENTERQUEUE") as caller,
          (
             select
                Cast(time as datetime) 
             from
                queue_log 
             where
                callid = t.callid 
                and event = "ENTERQUEUE"
          )
          as time1,
          (
             select
                queuename 
             from
                queue_log 
             where
                callid = t.callid 
                and event = "ENTERQUEUE"
          )
          as queue 
       from
          (
             select
                callid 
             from
                queue_log 
             where
                event in 
                (
                   "XITEMPTY",
                   "EXITWITHKEY",
                   "EXITWITHTIMEOUT",
                   "FULL",
                   "JOINEMPTY",
                   "JOINUNAVAIL",
                   "ABANDON"
                )
          )
          t
```

I think I've done a good enough job, but surely someone else could do better or has some important advice to share.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to [codereview.se]. However be sure to take their [tour](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) and read their [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page before posting.

Comment: I think you can ditch the subquery in the first query and just inner join the tables directly.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I'm curious of what you're trying with your subquery there. Can you clarify? thanks

Comment: Its unclear why a `inner join queue_log b` is there, there will always be a self match against `a`. So add a reason for it to be there, or if it doesn't need to be there, change the subquery into a part of the join.

Comment: You are right, the subquery isn't needed.

Comment: We really need to see the table structures so we know which table(s) `disposition` and `billsec` and `uniqueid` are in.  Also, this seems to violate `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` (which won't be enforced until a much later version.)

Comment: And, is the CAST needed?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @FanoFN and @danblack, the subquery isn't necessary so the query can be done in this way:

```
select
   t1.queuename,
   t.accountcode as agent,
   TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Cast(t1.time as datetime), t.calldate) as recall_time 
from
   daily_cdr t
inner join 
   queue_log t1
   on t.dst = t1.data2
where
   t1.event = "ENTERQUEUE"
   and t.disposition = "ANSWERED" 
   and t.billsec > 0 
   and t.calldate > Cast(t1.time as datetime) 
   and t.accountcode is not null 
group by
   t.uniqueid;
```